# Возможно ли изменить высоту строк в TTreeView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Возможно ли изменить высоту строк в TTreeView?

Comment: Изменить размер Fonta'а не пробовали?

Comment: @Oleg53 при увеличении высоты строк, величина шрифта должна остаться прежней. У TListBox есть свойство ItemHeigth, которое позволяет это воплотить, но вот у TTreeView я ничего подобного ещё не нашел(

Comment: Вот пример когда [выводится сразу 3 ноды](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21003726/2546083). Можно адаптировать под себя.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21003726/2546083):

```
procedure SetNodeHeight(Node: TTreeNode; Integral: Integer);
var
  ItemEx: TTVItemEx;
begin
  if not Node.Deleting then
  begin
    ItemEx.mask := TVIF_HANDLE or TVIF_INTEGRAL;
    ItemEx.hItem := Node.ItemId;
    ItemEx.iIntegral := Integral;
    TreeView_SetItem(Node.Handle, ItemEx);
  end;
end;
```